# OAuth2 Access origin error

Tags: javascript, azure, cors, oauth-2.0

I Request an `authorization code` from `OAuth2` Server.
My purpose is to authorize user with my microsoft App.
Refered [Document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code/)

My attempt for get Call:

```
function httpGet(){
        var theUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id="client_id"&response_type=code&redirect_uri="redirect_uri"&response_mode=query&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fservice.contoso.com%2F&state=12345";

        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('GET', theUrl, true);
        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (req.readyState === 4) {
                if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400) {
                    console.log(req.responseText)
                } else {
                    console.log("error")
                }
            }
        };
        req.send();
    }
```

but this gives below error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

then I add the  `req.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`

but it gives the below error:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Comment: You need to configure this on the server, not the Angular app

Comment: @jonrsharpe What do you mean by "You need to configure this on the server"?

Comment: I mean the server you're making the request to. Although that appears to be out of your control.

Comment: I am trying to request OAuth2 server.

Comment: Yes I understand that. But the server needs to know which origins it is supposed to respond to. Maybe there's some config you need to add; see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28283037/angularjs-spa-access-cors-webapi-secured-on-azure-ad

Comment: If there is no CORS headers present that means they don't want you calling that endpoint through AJAX most likely. Shouldn't you be redirecting the user browser there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using any `frontend` google libraries I came up with solution.

```
window.open("url")
```

After complete the authentication I get the `code` from `url params` and send it `backend` and achieve the `access token, refersh token.......etc,`

Answer (score 1):

To integrate AAD in javascript, we suggest you to use [azure-activedirectory-library-for-js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) which is a library in javascript for frontend to integrate AAD with a ease.

There are 2 options we need to pay attention on before we use ADAL for JS:

- According the node at https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-jQuery-CORS#step-6--run-the-sample:

  > Note This sample will not work in Internet Explorer. Please use a different browser, such as Google Chrome. ADAL.js uses an iframe to get CORS API tokens for resources other than the SPA's own backend. These iframe requests require access to the browser's cookies to authenticate with Azure Active Directory. Unfortunately, cookies are not accessible to Internet Explorer when the app is running in localhost.
- Enable the `oauth2AllowImplicitFlow` of your Azure AD application. Refer to https://crmdynamicsblog.wordpress.com/2016/03/17/response-type-token-is-not-enabled-for-the-application-2/ for the detailed steps.

Here is the code sample to acquire access token from Microsoft Graph:

```
<script src="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/lib/1.0.10/js/adal.min.js"></script>

<body>
<a href="#" onclick="login();">login</a>
<a href="#" onclick="getToken()">access token</a>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var configOptions = {
        tenant: "<tenant_id>", // Optional by default, it sends common
        clientId: "<client_id>",
        postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
    }
    window.authContext = new AuthenticationContext(configOptions);

    var isCallback = authContext.isCallback(window.location.hash);
    authContext.handleWindowCallback();

    function getToken(){
        authContext.acquireToken("https://graph.microsoft.com",function(error, token){
            console.log(error);
            console.log(token);
        })
    }
    function login(){
        authContext.login();
    }
</script>
```